pygame._sdl2 and SDL2 - Efficient Texture Storage on GPU with Multple Renderers
I'm working in pygame._sdl2 so that I can create multiple (2) windows simultaneously.  I think this is an SDL2 question, not specific to pygame:
I want to be able to blit() the same textures into both windows (at different times).  From what I've been able to tell, an SDL2 Texture is associated with a particular Renderer.  So it seems like I have to create 2 Textures for each source image - one for each Renderer.
Since Textures live on the GPU, am I doubling my GPU storage requirements?
Is there a way to have a single memory resource that can draw to both Renderers?  Or is there another way to improve GPU memory usage?
I'm working in Windows and Raspberry Pi, so I imagine my GPU storage availability on the RPi will be pretty limited.
I have tried working with Surfaces, but those won't blit() into the Renderer:
import pygame as pg
from pygame._sdl2 import Window, Texture, Image, Renderer, get_drivers, messagebox

pg.display.init()
win = Window("My Window", resizable=True)
ren = Renderer(win)
srf = pg.image.load("image.png")
ren.blit(srf, pg.Rect(300,100,100,100))

This gives:
TypeError: source must be drawable
which is odd, since blit() does not do any drawing on the source, only reading from it.  I assume that "drawable" is referring to data being in GPU memory, but I might be wrong about that.
One thing I was thinking about is to create a single Texture and then update() it with multple Surfaces (many of my textures are the same size).  But as I understand it update() requires copying from CPU memory to GPU memory and is slow.

Did you see the warning about _sdl2 not being ready for primetime and only suitable for pygame developers and those in communication with them? I suspect you don't quite fit that category and are engaging in premature optimization. It would be probably more suitable for you to develop your application using supported methods and then iterate. Or use a different library more suited to performance

Short answer: no. SDL2 does not allow sharing Textures between Renderers, and Renderers are tied 1:1 to Windows.
(Note that SDL can use different graphic APIs internally and that some of them are strictly tied to a single window per context)
Of course you're not the first one to have this idea.
Since SDL2 was released 2013 and SDL2 support in pygame/pygame-ce is still in development over 10 years later, I wouldn't bet on sdl3 implementing this and making it available in pygame in the near future.
